# How to differentiate between hold click and drag in Phaser?

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, phaser-framework

How to know the distance of the Drag, unused PositionUP or onInputUp to differentiate a drag from a long click?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvVsN.pnghttp://www.html5gamedevs.com/uploads/monthly_07_2014/post-9642-0-48696600-1405440289.png

it is a some code:

```
var fnd = game.add.group();
var o = fnd.create(game.world.randomX, game.world.randomY, 'fon'); 
o.events.onDragStart.add(this.DragActivo, this); 
DragActive = function (image) {  
   //When something has been moved is drag but when something has been pressed for long time is clicked
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property `sprite.input.dragDistanceThreshold = 3;` in order to start dragging only if the pointer moves a minimum amount of pixels when after `onInputDown`.

[Here's the doc](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.InputHandler.html#dragDistanceThreshold)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem that you have to do something like this.

I used the function mouseup and inside this one I placed the mousemove to recognize when the mouse moves it is a drag, if it does not do it is a very long click

because this framework does not have

Comment: can you provide an example if you still have the code?